How should I connect a 2x6 deck post to a 2x6 beam?
I have a small floating deck (jut a few ft off the ground). The pillars are 2x6 and the beams are 2x6. Current pillars are just nailed on the sides of the 2x6 beams. Not sure if this is the best. But I am adding concrete footings (right now, they are just resting on a single concrete pad) and a few additional footings.
I am looking for the right way and/or the right Simpson StrongTie connectors for the following joint:

Is it correct to nail the footings side ways? Or is it better to have them under the beams?

Never seen single 2xanything used as posts.  Even as beams you see more than one 2x.  For weight carrying you want them under.

Yeah, that seems like a flaw. A 2x6 doesn't have the rigidity on the flat axis to act as a post. 4x4 or 6x6 are more standard. For that reason you're unlikely to find a Simpson product for that use case.

I see. Ok, the existing ones I will still leave. And since they are wrong anyway, I'll leave them nailed to the sides. For the new ones I can get 4x4. Could you point me to the right Simpson connectors for 4x4 to 2x6 joint? Something like this (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Simpson-Strong-Tie-BC-Galvanized-Post-Cap-for-4x6-Nominal-Lumber-BC46/100374964) but I am not able to find 4x4 to 2x6

Usually posts are connected to beams, which are usually two or more 2x?.  Single 2x? do not have much tipping protection.  Even single 2x? joists usually/should have blocking to prevent tipping.  A few feet is 3 plus feet, so a collapse is worst than just being on deck blocks above the ground.  Your local building department should have regulations on what is allowed/needed, if not, quite a few deck designs will be online.

Well, it seems this floating deck is not done properly anyway, without permits (was there before I moved in). So, at this point, regulations are less of my concerns and I won't tear it apart completely. It's gonna be replaced anyway in 5 years or so (but not now). The only thing is I need to add 4 new posts to the existing 2x6 beams (it was previously connected to the exterior wall -- also in the wrong manner -- which is already removed). So my question is what the best way given the circumstances are.

@divB Are you sure that your region requires a permit for a floating deck? Most don't.

If I had to make this better, I’d bolt a 2x6 on each side, up to near the top of the 2x6 joist. I’m thinking about a dozen 4” structural screws from both sides.

@AdamO good point. I just checked and for my city it’s “18’’ above grade”. I measured and my deck is roughy 28’’ above grade. So seems it would, strictly speaking

@AloysiusDefenestrate the thing is, only a few planks of the deck have been removed. This is where I want to add additional posts. Adding 2x6 over the whole beam is hence not practical. I could add just a bit on the section without the deck planks, but if there any point doing this?

Sorry, wasn’t clear: I was suggesting a 3 ply post that held the joist like a bridle joint.

@AloysiusDefenestrate Oh i see. You mean sth like this? https://snipboard.io/c1btAN.jpg

@divB bummer! Cut the posts down 10". Problem solved :D

@divB — yes, and run them all to the ground for as much rigidity and screw space as possible

For this connection (in the drawing) probably nail plates. like are used in trusses.

Is it correct to nail the footings side ways? Or is it better to have them under the beams?

If beside Bolt them sideways,
If underneath use nail plates.
bolted is probably stronger

Bolted is also easier. So then, I’ll just bolt them sideways, as the existing ones. Question: are 10 x 3-1/2” PowerPro One Multi-Material screws good for this? I’d have a pack of these at home

Also, if bolted sideways, how many bolts are even needed?
